# How do I get my .NET application's path (not the path of the application that started my application)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am having trouble getting the path of my application's executable file at runtime. This application is being started by another executable and whenever I try to use Application.ExecutablePath I get the path to that application instead of mine.

```
Dim aPath1 As String = Application.ExecutablePath()
Dim aPath2 As String = Application.StartupPath()
```

in C# it would be

```
string aPath1 = Application.ExecutablePath;
string aPath2 = Application.StartupPath;
```

Neither of these give me the path of the program in which those two lines are exectured, they only tell what program started this program.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because I don't care if the answer is in VB or C#. I'll take whatever I can get.

Comment: try this AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory also what path are you specifically trying to get..? are you using app.config or web.config files at all as well within your project..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx

Answer (score 5):

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` will get you what you want in most cases.

Alternatively, this will get you the location of the assembly which is executing the code:

`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```